# Testing with two versions of Catalyst on the same system/application

Tags: perl, catalyst

I'm trying to test a client's Catalyst application that works with `Catalyst 5.8` and has some serious problems with `Catalyst 5.9`.

I'm having to do this on their test system where the application [which has a complex and messy install too] is running with `Catalyst 5.8`.

I'm wondering whether there's a clean way of switching back and forwards?

I'm thinking, for example,  install 5.9 in a custom directory, go use `Catalyst::Runtime '5.80';` or `use Catalyst::Runtime '5.90';` and switch `@INC` around to suit.

However, Because of some of the deeper changes, I suspect that the application might have to be re-built for 5.9 anyway.

I can't really make a lot of deep changes to the environment, it's not my system, so it's an implementation problem and a coding one, all mixed up.

Any commentary on this welcome, I'm not a deep Catalyst expert, so I'm hoping for a simple way to do this.

Comment: `use Module VERSION` might not be doing what you think. All it does is load `Module` from the usual place, and croak if the version isn't at least `VERSION`. To load a specific version of a module, you'll want to manipulate `@INC`

Comment: Thanks, a sad truth [!] and thanks for reminding me...

Answer (score 2):

Use [local::lib](http://search.cpan.org/~apeiron/local-lib-1.008004/lib/local/lib.pm) to install a different Catalyst version

Comment: Thanks also, I'll have ask the sysadmins, but this may be a way through. Unhappily, I'm also going to have to scramble around and see what's on there already too...

Comment: @Julian, yes, this is looking viable thanks. I've tried this on a local machine as a 'rehearsal' for the client's remote machine. Got a new Catalyst in ~/local_perl/lib/perl5/ via local::lib [probably could have used installation prefix] and then prepended the path when I run a preload-modules script on Apache start. Logging shows Catalyst coming up as the 'local' version.